# How to select an EMI suppressor

Tags: switching-regulator, emi-filtering

I have come to the part in my construction where I suppress EMI. I just need a little help on how to select the right one.

I'm using two RT8259 switch regulators (switching at 1.4MHz) and want to suppress the switch frequencies EMI on the 24v DC input.

I can I calculate the L1 value from the switch frequency?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsVe7e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you even sure you have differential mode noise? What measurements have you done on EMI?

Comment: **"I have come to the part in my construction where I suppress EMI"**... Well there is your FIRST mistake.

Comment: I recently took over the role as designer, I don't have years of experience. My predecessor (R.I.P) had. We had a lot of EMI problems in the past and I'm simply trying to limit possible EMI on all the problematic places. Meaning all board connectors with "longer" cables attached. So, yes, this place caused EMI problems for us in the past and we have always had some sort of suppression here. I'm just simply asking for help on how to calculate L1 based on the switching frequencies.

Comment: The problem is that you assertion that a particular switching frequency calls for a particular diff mode filter value which in turns solves your EMI. You need to step way back and take a much broader look.

Comment: So I should just design without any EMI considerations and after manufacturing try to deal with possible EMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your buck requlator draws a HF square wave current from the 24V power supply. If you want to avoid problems, the issue is smoothing this current.

Your 10µF ceramic capacitors will already achieve most of this, provided they are properly placed and routed.

If you're feeling extra paranoid, you can add a LC filter on the input. This is a capacitor to ground between "F1" and "L1". L1 adds impedance, and the cap shorts the remaining noise to ground.

The inductor should be a ferrite bead of the proper current rating, make sure you get one specified for power lines (like murata BLM18PG series), not one for signal which will not handle much current. As for impedance, I have no inspiration at the moment, so let's say 30-60 ohms.

However there is an extra complication. Since your input supply is 24V and your switcher has an absolute maximum of 26V which is really close, you do want to avoid any ringing on the input voltage when someone connects the power from an already switched-on power supply. The ringing is caused by the capacitors in the supply and the wire and ferrite bead inductance. So I suggest adding an aluminium electrolytic capacitor at the input, the value doesn't matter, use something you already have on your BOM, but it should have enough ESR to damp the LC ringing.

Anyway, if you fail EMC it will most likely be about common mode noise, and this will not do anything about that. Common mode noise is handled by having a good placement on the board, a good layout, proper grounding etc.

If you had extreme EMC headaches in the past, you can hire a specialist consultant for a few hours so they may look at your board, this would most likely be cheaper than going into the test chamber and failing.

Comment: The headache was when EU forced everyone to limit EMC. Before that we hadn't taking EMC into the calculation and when we checked our boards they all had problems. After that we switched over to 4 layer boards, added capacitors on all "external" signals and suppressors on power and USB lines as a standard procedure at design. This solved all the EMI we had.

Comment: @MaxKielland I'd be concerned about adding much, if any, inductance here. Though you did not mention the currents involved, since it's feeding two switching regulators that's potentially a lot of current you're turning on and off, presumably asynchronously, between the two regulators. Extra inductance could actually make the EMI picture worse. You will also need to add a kickback diode to prevent the right side of the inductor from exceeding the regulator input voltage limit. I'd be adding multiple value decoupling caps instead. That and making sure you have a solid grounding scheme.

Comment: Yes if you add a LC filter and do not damp it by adding an aluminium electrolytic, then it will ring at a low frequency like 20-100kHz, but you have two switchers, which will work at different frequencies, they could generate a beat tone which will excite the LC resonance, so the inductor may do more harm than good. This is a good scenario for "5% of the boards don't work and we have no idea why"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input filter like this to filter switching from the load to the source, make sure the roll off point of the filter is lower than 1.4MHz. A better way is to use a ferrite bead to take advantage of frequency properties of ferrite.